# ucanaccess java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed

Tags: ucanaccess

I have been using ucanaccess in my project. Sometimes for unknown reason i get below error and the application will no more be accessible until i restart the app. Any Help in identifying the issue is much appreciated. Please do let me know for any further info. Thanks.

Sample Code :

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                String dbURL = ApplicationPropertiesSingleton.get(Constants.ETS_DB_URL);
                System.out.println("**********ETS DB URL =" + dbURL + "***************");
                File msAccessDBFile = new File(dbURL);
                boolean canRead = msAccessDBFile.canRead();
                System.out.println("Can MSAccess DB File Readable =" + canRead);
                ETS_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbURL + ";memory=false");

ucanaccess-3.0.3.1.jar<br>
jackcess-2.1.3.jar
```

Error Details :

```
ScriptWriter synch error: 
java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed
    at org.hsqldb.lib.FileUtil$FileSync.sync(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptWriterBase.forceSync(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.synchLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.finalizeHSQLDB(DBReference.java:376)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.closeHSQLDB(DBReference.java:342)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.checkLastModified(DBReference.java:259)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.checkLastModified(UcanaccessConnection.java:731)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.checkConnection(UcanaccessConnection.java:241)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.createStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:260)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:711)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ices.pts.action.SessionValidationFilter.doFilter(SessionValidationFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Comment: In continuation, this is how i get my connection "DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbURL + ";memory=false")"

Comment: From the logs, i dont see issue in getting connection. While executing the query the exception is thrown.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Is the Access database on a different machine from the one running your application, i.e., are you opening the database file over a network connection?

Comment: Gord - Yes. Application and the Ms Access data base are in two different servers.

Comment: With `memory=false`, UCanAccess will create the disk files for the HSQLDB backing database in a temporary subfolder of the same folder where the Access database resides. If the Access database is on a network share then it is usually better to use `mirrorFolder=C:/path/to/local/writable/folder` (which also implies `memory=false`) so the HSQLDB backing files will be local. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @user1570656 - BTW, you can use `mirrorFolder=java.io.tmpdir` to save the HSQLDB backing files in the system temporary folder. (Also, when replying to a comment, remember to use an "@" mention like I just did here.)

Comment: @Gord - Thanks Gord for the reply. Point noted

Comment: @Gord -  I will make changes as suggested and reply back if i see the issue again no later than this week. Again thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: @Gord - I made the changes as suggested and created a local mirror folder   in the server where application is running. But, after restarting the application (stop and start) i am seeing below error                                                                    `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 error in script file line: C:\ETS_Mirror\2049244085 362
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:264)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:379)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:330)`

Comment: @GordThompson - Changed to mirrorFolder instead of keepMirror solved the problem. Trying to understand the difference between them. Any suggestions is much appreciated. Thanks.